# Split method splitting by a string which includes spaces

Tags: powershell, split

Apologies if this is an obvious one, but I've tried so many things to make this work... In VB (which I'm more familiar with) I believe it would be fine.

I'm trying to split a string with e delimiter of " - ".
The spaces are crucial, as there are '-'s elsewhere in the string, but not to be delimited.

```
"This-string - contains - some-hyphens".Split(' - ')
```

This *should* (in my brain) return 3 elements:

```
This-string
contains
some-hyphens
```

Unfortunately, I getting 9+ elements depending on how I play with the `Split` method.

```
This
string


contains


some
hyphens
```

It's clearly splitting on `-` alone, but also seems to be splitting on spaces, and ignoring the `' - '` format.

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      17134  228
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`String.Split` method overload you're using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2) accepts `char[]`, so powershell is being nice and splitting up your string *for* you.  If you want to use a string, you need to pass `StringSplitOptions`:

```
'This-string - contains - some-hyphens'.Split((,' - '), [StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

In testing, I needed to use a unary array operator `,` to force the parser to use the correct overload.

---

The more powershell-esque way is to use the `-split` operator which operates using regex:

```
'This-string - contains - some-hyphens' -split ' - '
```

Comment: Thank you.  I used the operator, and it worked perfectly.  And the explanation helped in the understanding.

Answer (score 2):

What is happening is its splitting based off a array of chars. So " - " is like being split(" ","-").

In powershell you can use -split. -Split treats it as a full string " - "

```
"This-string - contains - some-hyphens" -split " - "
```

Answer (score 1):

When you provide it the .split method, it is separating on any character in the set that you provide.  This means your results will be split on either space, or hyphen.

If you use -split, the input will be treated as a string and not a set of characters.

Let's look at an example (provided below)

```
$foo = "This-string - contains - some-hyphens"
$bar = $foo -split(' - ')
$bar
```

Output below:

```
This-string
contains
some-hyphens
```